# Laravel 5.5 Get Posts order by sum of votes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello, I want to get most popular posts, I created a system where u can vote on Post or a Comment. [+1,-1]

**Vote Table**

- integer: id - vote id
- integer: model_id - model id
- string: model -model name ["App/Post","App/Comment"]
- integer: value - value of vote [-1,1]

Now i want to get posts ordered by sum of value. But I stucked in deadpool.

Here's is my actual code, unfortunately doesnt work.

```
DB::table('posts')
->join('votes','posts.id','votes.model_id')
->groupBy('votes.model_id')
->where('model','App\Post')
->select('posts.*','sum(\'votes.value\')')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fully read the manual [Laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects).

You need to use raw expression because it has aggregate function.

```
DB::table('posts')
    ->join('votes','posts.id','=','votes.model_id')
    ->groupBy('votes.model_id')
    ->where('model','App\Post')
    ->selectRaw('posts.*, sum(votes.value) as sum_value')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, but when I run it, everywhere I get sum('votes.value')": 0.0 If i change sum to count it giving me good value.

Comment: just made an edit, you are no need to quote the column